# Extjs Grid Mouseover show tooltip

Tags: extjs

I am new to Extjs and working on tooltip for Extjs 3.2 .My reqirement is that when i mouseover on extjs grid row it shows a tooltip.In tooltip i want to display remarks field value.

This is what i have tried

```
{header: "remarks",
         width: 120,
         sortable: true,
         dataIndex: 'remarks',
         renderer : function(value, metadata) {
             metadata.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
             return value;
             },
         editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: true
        }}
```

Also I have included following line

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

But Not Working any Help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe back then they used metadata.attr try that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tweek to the code. The function parameter metadata was defined, but  "meta" was used in the line below. It should be:

```
function(value, metadata) {
   metadata.attr = 'ext:qtip="' + value + '"';
   return value;
}
```

Comment: can i implement tooltip on row instead of coloumn,and show any one column value always

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try listener, for example
columns:
[
  {
    header: "remarks",
    width: 120,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'remarks'
  },
  {
    // Column #2
  },
  {
    // Column #3
  }
],

listeners:
{
  itemmouseenter: function(view, record, item, index, e, options)
                  {
                    var remarks = record.get('remarks');
                    var view = this.getView();
                    view.tip = Ext.create
                               (
                                 'Ext.tip.ToolTip',
                                 {
                                   delegate: view.itemSelector,
                                   trackMouse: true,
                                   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                                   target: view.el,
                                   listeners:
                                   {
                                     beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip)
                                                 {
                                                   tip.update("<b>Remarks: </b><div style='color:green;width:200px'>" + remarks + "</div><br>");
                                                 }   
                                   }
                                 }
                               );   
                  }                                             
}
```